# Firebase signInWithEmailAndPassword() 400() POST Error with INVALID_PASSWORD

Tags: angularjs, firebase

I’m currently implementing the new firebase auth() in my angularjs app with username and password.

```
firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
```

This is all working, until an incorrect password is supplied for a valid email address. The promise returns and I handle the event gracefully. However the console and network logs a 400

```
 POST https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/verifyPassword?key=[key] 400
```

The response body:

```
{
    "error": {
   "errors": [
    {
     "domain": "global",
     "reason": "invalid",
     "message": "INVALID_PASSWORD"
     }
    ],
    "code": 400,
    "message": "INVALID_PASSWORD"
     }
    }
```

I have seen all the previous questions on this and I can't find a response that will satisfy my app needs. Intended behaviour is to return an error response to the promise(which is what is does) but not also log to the user which piece of information is incorrect.

From a penetration test perspective this gives away valuable information to a user/hacker. Are there any other suggestions on how to handle this other than changing to another auth implementation?

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm running into the same issue when trying to log in with an invalid user email/password.

Comment: No, unfortunately not. I was concerned that signing up doesn't require a complex password, as I wasn't able to integrate with other sign in providers I increased the strength level of the users password using a custom form wrapper around the auth.